# EOF not working as expected (C)

Tags: c, while-loop, eof

I'm trying to use the EOF function but it doesn't work as I expect it. In the debugger mode it doesn't detect the second "scanf" function and just carries on. It keeps on missing out the "scanf" function now and then. Code is posted below

```
int main() {
    char tempString; 
    int i = 0; 
    printf("Enter your letter\n"); 
    scanf_s("%c", &tempString); 

    while (tempString != EOF) {

        printf("You entered:%c\n", tempString); 
        scanf_s("%c", &tempString);
    }
}
```

I have also tried it using the getchar() function but the same thing occurs, code is posted below:

```
int main() {
    char tempString; 
    int i = 0; 
    printf("Enter your letter\n"); 


    while ((tempString = getchar()) != EOF) {

        printf("You entered:%c\n", tempString); 

    }
}
```

Thanks for reading

Comment: `tempString` should be `int`

Comment: `char tempString;` -->> `int tempString;` in the second ptogram. In the first program you could check the return from scanf(). (and scanf_s() is nonsense)

Comment: @wildplasser scanf_s is the term for visual studios

Comment: @pzaenger i changed the char to int and it didn't make a difference and plus i am using char because I am detecting a letter

Comment: `scanf_s` *returns* EOF on eof or failure, it doesn't populate the output parameter with EOF, so checking it is worthless. `scanf_s` has a return code for a reason; use it (hint: in your while condition and eliminating the tail-call to `scanf_s` would be worth trying). For your second case, `int` is indeed the proper decl for `tempString` . And I hope you realize in *either* case the follow-up carriage-return/linefeed *you* entered by hitting <enter> on your kb doesn't disappear into thin air. It will be waiting in the input stream on the next loop iteration.

Comment: `EOF` isn't an actual end of file character you read, it's just a value some functions return to indicate that they encountered the end of a file/stream.  On end of file, there's usually no EOF character for `scanf()` or `scanf_s()`  to read, they'll simply indicate that they failed through their return value.  Though there is such a thing as an end of file character (in some situations only, it's not always used), it's not the same thing as the `EOF` constant/macro you're using.

Comment: What do you "expect from EOF function", as you say? Since when is EOF a function in C, please? Did you try inputing EOF by pressing `control+D`? BTW, `scanf_s()` is not standard C, it is a Microsoft specific extension.

Comment: Besides being nonsense, scanf_s() needs an **additional argument**, which you do not provide. (your compiler should warn about this). That could make the program even more dangerous. (not in this case, "%c" is relatively harmless)

Comment: I've just put two solutions up, the getchar() function is the one i used initially but i wasn't getting the right answer therefore i used the scanf() function. The scanf() function isn't recognised in visual studios so you have to use scanf_s(). 
For the getchar function if you press ctrl + z and it finishes the function

Comment: The buffer size requirement includes `%c` too. [Please see this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx) which has *buffer size to be specified for all input parameters of type c, C, s, S, or string control sets that are enclosed in []. The buffer size in characters is passed as an additional parameter immediately following the pointer to the buffer or variable.*

Comment: @BiaKhan says "The `scanf()` function isn't recognised in visual studios". That is quite untrue, VS gives a warning, which can be defeated if you don't like to go too far MS's way. You can defeat the MS warnings about standard library functions by adding`#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` before any `#include` header files.

Comment: can someone please post the code for this, this question has been asked countless times on this forum and I can't seem to find a definitive code for this. 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

EDIT:

Firstly you omitted the length argument required by `scanf_s` for `%c` and `%s` formats.

Second, the `%c` format takes the *next character from the input buffer*. At the second (and subsequent) entries there was a `newline` left in the input buffer from the first input. Adding a `space` before the `%c` format specifier cleans off that leading whitespace.

Other formats, such as `%s` and `%d` **do** ignore leading whitespace, but not `%c`.

Thirdly, with `scanf` the use of `EOF` is not the way to go, you should control the loop with the return value from `scanf` which tells you the number of items successfully read.

This program starts by using `scanf_s`. The second entry ignores the `newline` after the first entry.

Then it moves to using `getchar`. In this test the function return value is `int`, so that's my data type here. That way `EOF` (-1) won't conflict with any required character data. Note that `getchar` starts by reading the `newline` left after the previous `scanf_s` (which only ignores *leading* whitespace.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char ch_scanf;                                  // char type
    int ch_getchar;                                 // int type
    printf("Using scanf_s\n");
    if (scanf_s(" %c", &ch_scanf, 1) == 1) {        // consumes any leading whitespace
        printf("scanf_s value: %d\n", ch_scanf);
    }
    if (scanf_s(" %c", &ch_scanf, 1) == 1) {        // consumes any leading whitespace
        printf("scanf_s value: %d\n", ch_scanf);
    }

    printf("\nUsing getchar\n");
    while ((ch_getchar = getchar()) != EOF) {
        printf("getchar value: %d\n", ch_getchar);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Sample session:

```
Using scanf_s
A
scanf_s value: 65
B
scanf_s value: 66

Using getchar
getchar value: 10
C
getchar value: 67
getchar value: 10
^Z
```

Finally if you want to use the standard library function `scanf` without MSVC ticking you off, you can do it like this

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
```

Comment: firstly thanks for posting an answer, but i don't see you using the EOF function with a while loop

Comment: @BiaKhan if have revised the answer to compare the use of `scanf_s` and `getchar`... note that `EOF` is not a function. It is an macro giving an integer value.

Comment: The reason why using `EOF` is not the best way to control `scanf_s` is because that won't trap invalid input when it is *not* end-of-file. Such as entering wrong data type, and `scanf_s` returns `0` items converted.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char tempString;

    printf("Enter your letter\n");

    while (scanf_s("%c%*c", &tempString, 1) != EOF) {//%*c for consume newline, 1 is buffer size
        printf("You entered:%c\n", tempString);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

```
int tempString;//int for check EOF

printf("Enter your letter\n"); 

while ((tempString = getchar()) != EOF) {
    printf("You entered:%c\n", tempString);
    getchar();//consume newline
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour of scanf() function in C

> Is to read the input from the keyboard buffer till it encounters EOF (ie; till we
>    press enter key)

In general, it is not advisable to use "%c" in C to read an input character because

> The value is collected in keyboard buffer till we hit enter and we could not restrict user entering single character

So, the best way to obtain a character is by using getchar() function.

In the program you have provided you can use any other character to check for end and not `EOF` since it is used in `scanf()` implementation to mark the input end.

You may other keys like `esc` to check for the end

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define esc 27

int main()
{
    char ch;

    while((ch = getchar()) != esc) {

         //print the entered character here
    }
}
```

To know in depth about `scanf()` implementation look into this [scanf() source code](http://www.jbox.dk/sanos/source/lib/scanf.c.html)

Comment: _In function `main`: undefined reference to `getch`_. I guess, it should be `getchar()`? If so, then it should also be `int ch;`.

Comment: Yeah! It's getchar() according to C99. Have edited the code. @pzaenger

Comment: "till it encounters EOF" is not "till we press enter key", which may be end of line but not end of file (and `scanf()` will read past end of line anyway).  You seem to be associating line buffering with `scanf()`... but line buffering is a separate thing that happens before input gets to `scanf()` or other input functions and doesn't change what input can be read, only when.  Also, `getch()` is non-standard, and isn't really equivalent to `getchar()` anyway -- one is not a newer version of the other... they're just different functions that do similar things, but in different ways.